# iOS: Determine if another app becomes active

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, background-process

My app needs the device location with an accuracy of about 10 meters. If the app is launched, it usually takes e.g. 10 sec to get the required accuracy. This delay is OK. However when the app is „in use“ (see below), the delay should be less, e.g. 1 sec.

The problem is the following:

When the user switches off the display, the app transits from the active state to the background state (and the delegate methods `applicationWillResignActive` and `applicationDidEnterBackground` are called).
Normally, location updates are not done in background. So, next time the app transits from background to active state (delegate methods `applicationWillEnterForeground` and `applicationDidBecomeActive` are called), the location manager needs again e.g. 10 sec to reach the required accuracy. This delay in unfortunately not OK.

To avoid it, the app could do location updates in the background. This works fine.
The disadvantage is that these background location updates continue, even if the app is no longer used, because the user pressed the home button and switched to another app. This is disturbing at least for 2 reasons: The GPS hardware is unnecessarily active and uses power, and the user is notified that my app is using the device location although this is no longer required.

My question thus is:

Is it possible to determine if another app becomes active?
If so, background location updates could be switched off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to determine if another app becomes active?

No, your app only knows if it's in background or in foreground handling delegate events. Know if user opened another app or is in the home screen is not possible.

> These background location updates continue, even if the app is no longer used, because the user pressed the home button and switched to another app.

I think you're right. You could start a timer when application goes in background and update localization only for an estabilished period (one minute?). Then, at the end of timer count save last localization coordinates. Timer is used to avoid unnecessary updates, then if user doesn't open again your app after a reasonable time, maybe it's because he's using other apps or he locked the device.

When the app comes to the foreground again, if timer is still active you're good. Otherwise show last localization saved and show a small "banner" to advise user that localization could not be accurated for the first 10 seconds (until when required accuracy has been reached)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was afraid that it would not be possible to determine if another app becomes active. Unfortunately, your suggestion with the timer does not solve my problem, since the app may be "in use" from minutes to, say, 2 hours.